# Integrating Kernels and Eigenvectors numerically

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, hilbert-spaces

For $C_{ij}$ is a given matrix, I would like solve the eigenvalue problem,

\begin{align}
\int C\left(t, t^{\prime}\right) a_{n}\left(t^{\prime}\right) d t^{\prime}=\lambda^{(n)} a_{n}(t)
\end{align}

If there were not integration, then numerically I can (eg in matlab) just call eig(); for and the numerical integration I can use trapz(), however we do not yet know the eigenvector $a_n(t)$. Any idea how I can approach this problem? It is occuring in the context of POD analysis.

**Edit:** What class of problem is this with both the integral and eigenvalue problem? I would appreciate it if anyone has some pointers to the literature

Comment: Discretize by hand and then use eig is one way. Not the only way...

Comment: @Ian Can you point me to some books with examples on this?

Comment: I would approach this by applying quadrature to the integral, writing it as a matrix product, and using any standard eigenvalue algorithm. Which quadrature you should use is a question of the properties of $C$.

Comment: @superckl Great, thanks. That's what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation#Numerical_solution seems to say also

Comment: You say that Cij is a matrix, but then you write C(t,t') as a function, which is it? Please be more clear.  Also, is your integration definite? If so, what are the limits?

Comment: @superckl doesn't the weights depend on eigenfunction?

Comment: @georg Following the suggestion above, no. If $a_n$ were given, then you could use any quadrature rule to evaluate the left side. Doing that gives you a matrix which depends on the quadrature rule and on $C$; its eigenvalues are approximately eigenvalues of the original problem. You can reconstruct approximate eigenfunctions by interpolating, using the entries of the eigenvectors as function values at nodes.

Comment: (Cont.) For example if you use the trapezoidal rule then you have $A_{i,1}=h C_{i,1}/2,A_{i,n}=h C_{i,n}/2$ and for $1<j<n$ you have $A_{i,j}=h C_{i,n}$. Here $C_{i,j}=C(t_i,t_j)$ and $h$ is the step size. If $C$ is $C^2$ then this will converge at the rate you would expect from the trapezoidal rule (unless it is periodic in the second argument and smoother than $C^2$, in which case it will converge faster).